# Measure of connectivity in Graph States

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, quantum-information, graph-theory

Given $G = (V,E)$, with the set of vertices $V$ and the set of edges $E$, the corresponding graph state is defined as
$$|G\rangle = \prod_{(a,b)\in E} U^{\{a,b\}} |+\rangle ^{\otimes V}$$
where the operator $U^{\{a,b\}}$ is the controlled-$Z$ interaction between the two vertices $a$ and $b$. Further, we define an operator $S_v$ for each vertex $v$ of $G$ :
$$S_v = \sigma_x^{(v)} \prod_{u\in N(v)} \sigma^{(u)}_z$$
where $N(v)$ is the set of vertices adjacent to $v$. The graph state $|G\rangle$ is the simultaneous $+1$-eigenvalue eigenstate of the $N$ operators $\{S_v\}_{v\in V}$
$$S_v |G\rangle = |G\rangle \qquad \forall \ v\in V$$

---

Given the graph state $|G\rangle$, Is there a way to measure the connectivity of node $a$ and $b$? The connectivity is defined as $1$ if the two nodes are connected; otherwise, it's zero. In a similar sense, I want to define an operator $C^{(a,b)}$ such that
$$\langle G|C^{(a,b)}|G\rangle = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if nodes are connected} \\
0 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the two cases (connected vs not connected) cannot be distinguished deterministically. This can be easily seen from the 2-vertex case, since the states $\lvert+\rangle\lvert+\rangle$ and the 2-site graph state are not orthogonal. However, this does not prevent you from constructing an operator $C$ as desired (it will just have eigenvalues outside the interval $[0;1]$).

Now for the general case, you can use that projecting sites onto $\lvert0\rangle$ erases a vertex from a graph state. Thus, an operator $C^(a,b)$ can be obtained by projecting all sites but $a$ and $b$ onto $\lvert0\rangle$ and then proceeding as above.

Note, however, that the resulting operator needs to be rescaled exponentially (as each projection has success rate $\lvert0\rangle$. This can be improved if you know something about the underlying graph: A $Z$ measurement on a vertex will erase that vertex, and give rise to a $Z$ on all adjacent (i.e., connected) vertices, which can subsequently corrected. If you have no such information, however, then you cannot correct for the $Z$ (and under random $Z$'s, the two states above are not distinguishable (didn't check it carefully, though)).